# How to animate a mesh being unravelled?

Tags: animation, mesh

Note: I am a beginner at blender.

I'd like to have a mesh appear as though it is being unravelled.

My idea is to have it stand in front of a hole, and then for the hole to suck the model in, but in a long strand rather than the whole mesh at once.

Is this possible?

Comment: What is the mesh? When I hear unraveled, I think of a rug.

Comment: Can you post a picture of your mesh and/or the effect you're looking for?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELHoNz1jtTU